# Return Logged User's Posts Into laravelcollective/html Select Dropdown Menu Within a Form

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I am trying to pass only the posts created by the logged in user into a laravelcollective/html select drop down menu within a form.

In my code I have two examples. Using the variable **example** shows how I can get the dropdown select menu to show all results from the posts table. Using the variable **posts** in a foreach loop shows how I can return just the posts created by the logged user, but not in a select menu.

I need to have the dropdown menu function as in the form using **example** but displaying results of the foreach **posts** loop.

**Controller**

```
public function createPost() 
{
  $example = Post::pluck('title', 'id')->all();
  $posts = Posts::all();

  return view('post.create', compact('posts', 'example'));
}
```

**Example View**

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('example', 'Posts:') !!}
  {!! Form::select('example', ['' => 'Select'] + $example, null) !!}
</div>
```

**Foreach Loop Posts View**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  @if(Auth::user()->id == $post->user_id)
    {{ $post->title }} <br>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try  `$posts = Posts::where('user_id',\Auth::id())->get()->pluck('title','');`. It will return only posts of logged in user.

```
{{ Form::select('example', $posts) }}
```

You are using select box wrong.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  @if(Auth::user()->id == $post->user_id)
    {{ $post->title }} <br>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can someone please give my question a +1? I have been banned from asking questions after I asked this one. I thought this was a good one.

Answer (score 3):

I would update your controller to only return posts by the user rather than rely on the foreach check if `Auth::user()->id == $post->user_id`

```
public function createPost()
{
  $posts = Posts::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

  return view('post.create', compact('posts'));
}
```

As a side note, your method should probably just be `create()` to keep inline with the standard CRUD.

Then in your blade,

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('post', 'Posts:') !!}
  {!! Form::select('post', ['' => 'Select'] + $posts, null) !!}
</div>
```